# How Do Android Devices Render Themes?

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design

I am a bit confused, as I have different values folders:

```
styles.xml in values
styles.xml in values-v21
```

I understand that a lot of AppCompat themes were made available in API 21. In my styles.xml folder I am implementing the following theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Isn't this theme an AppCompat theme? How do Android devices running API < 21 actually render this theme if it was only released for devices > API 21?

Comment: The whole idea of that AppCompat thing is that it's not a part of any particular Android release, but a separate library, so you can use it on older systems as well.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, do you want to mark as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like my answer, here's the more elaborate version:

The whole idea of that AppCompat thing is that it's not a part of any particular Android release, but a separate library, so you can use it on older systems as well.

API 21 introcuded Material theme. On APIs where Material theme is available, AppCompat uses Material. On older APIs AppCompat mimics certain things to make it work and look more or less like Material.

AppCompat themes were there long before API 21. When APIs 11 - 20 were 'the most recent', there was AppCompat theme with Holo look, which was compatible with 2.x line.

In x-v21 folders you should have things, which are not compatible with AppCompat theme. For example drawables with `<ripple>` tags, because ripples are not supported on pre-21. AppCompat internally has ripples in `drawable-v21` folder and corresponding static colors in plain `drawable` folder.